# Python - Verifying if variable is empty

Tags: python

I am writing a script that logs into a remote node via SSH and checks for a service being up by saving the output of `pgrep -a <service-name>` , storing it in a variable and checking if that variable is UP or not.

```
HOST="172.29.219.110"
COMMAND="pgrep -a haproaxy"
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
print ( result )
if result == "":
   print ("The service is NOT running")
else:
   print ("The service is running")
```

If I run the above as it is, I get the below response:

```
[b'31318 /usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid\n', b'31319 /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds\n', b'31320 /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -Ds\n']
The service is running
```

But when I `pgrep` a bogus service, the response is

```
[]
The service is running
```

Ive checked on the remote server that `pgrep -a haaaaaaaaa` retuns nothing. But it doesnt seem to register as an empty variable in python. What is it that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Result is a list. You can check for an empty list with if not list:

Comment: use `if not result`. Or `if result == []`

Comment: `[]` is simply not the same as `""`.

Comment: That's a pretty crappy way to check whether the service is up, for what it's worth.  I can think of multiple failure modes.

Comment: I'd say swap your conditional and just use `if result: #good else: #bad`

Comment: @wim Can you suggest a better way please ? Im trying to make things the best they can be. Im new to Python so I have much to learn.

Comment: Why don't you tell `haproxy` to save its list of PIDs to a file that you can read/check? See `-p <pidfile>` in the `haproxy` man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/haproxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are equating a list with an empty string. That is why your code fails. The correct answer to this would be:

```
if not result:
  print("The service is not running")
```